# Select additional worksheets when merging workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to parse data from multiple workbooks with multiple sheets into a single workbook that summarizes the data. So far I have been able to combine a specified range of data, from multiple workbooks, into a single file. However I would like to also include data from the worksheets within the workbooks.
How do I modify the range to include additional worksheets?

```
'Creates a new workbook
'Reads data
'Writes data to the workbook
'Format the data in the workbook

Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range

' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "C:\attach\"

' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = 1

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx*")

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""
    ' Open a workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

    ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
    SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName


    ' Here Is where I need to specify additional sheets, I think.
    ' Modify this range for your workbooks.
    ' It can span multiple rows.
    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(2).Range("A1:B7") <====

    ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
    ' be the same size as the source range.
    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
    Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
       SourceRange.Columns.Count)

    ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
    DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

    ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
    NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
' data is readable.
SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
```

End Sub